# Access folder with os

Tags: python, operating-system

I want to iterate over a folder using a for-loop and os.listdir(), I'm just wondering what exactly to write into the brackets to access a particular file. Thanks!

Comment: os.listdir(path)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example should help you:

```
import os

path = "C:/Users/TestDir"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

for file in dirs:
    print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily google that. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm
You only need the path in the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

According to what i understood, you would like to iterate over files inside a particular folder until you find one particular file? You could do something like:

```
import os

FileToBeFound = "Your File Name To Find"
path = "Path to the directory you would like to check for a file in"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file == FileToBeFound:
        #do stuff with file
        break
    else:
        continue
```